# Passing Data From iPhone app to PHP file

Tags: php, iphone, ios

What is the best way to pass data input from an iphone app to a php file?

Comment: A PHP file? I guess you mean a PHP application running on a webserver? You should probably clarify your question. 
You'll probably get a lot of answers, too, since there is no clear "best way".

Comment: A fair assumption, but the PHP file is located on an external, web-accessible server - correct?

Comment: `HTTP`, unless you want to roll your own protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NSURLRequest POST or GET call to the php file.

```
- (void) <functionname>:<parameters> {   
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<url with GET>",<parameters>];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];  NSError * e; 
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&e];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about posting the data to a web server, I'd recommend using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to HTTP POST the data to the server in Json format. You'd then use the PHP function [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode the data.

[Json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) is a good Json framework for the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I like to simply make a `URLRequest`, set its method to `@"POST"`, and using a simple xml just send it as the body of the request. Finally with a `NSURLConnection` and its delegate methods you verify and add more actions depending on the method being called at a given time.

With the `connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` delegate method you can handle a response from your php side.

But if all you are doing is receiving something like an `XML`, you can just make the request to the url and send it to a parser; in this case I usually use `NSXMLParser`.