# Send iPhone data to PHP file

Tags: php, iphone, sql, objective-c, database

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [iPhone: Post data to php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231104/iphone-post-data-to-php-page)
>   [Passing Data From iPhone app to PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495738/passing-data-from-iphone-app-to-php-file)

What is the best way to send simple numerical and textual data from an iphone app to a php application?

Essentially what I am trying to do is to get the data input by users sent to a php file so it can be stored in a remote database.

What is the best way to send data from an iphone app to a php app so it can be stored in a MYSQL database...

Comment: See also [iPhone PHP integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311933/iphone-php-integration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you know which fields are being sent, there is nothing to stop you sending the data via post, but make sure you validate/sanitise on the php side.

if you choose to go this route, I would have a look at http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use NSURLRequest to post data to a PHP file on your server. There are also some libraries out there such as http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ which you could use instead.